# Log4j2 not logging to console

Tags: java, logging, log4j2

I cannot get [Log4j 2](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/) to log to the console. Nothing is showing up when running with gradle.

`log4j2.xml` in the projects root directory:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration status="ALL">
    <Appenders>
        <Console name="Console" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
            <PatternLayout pattern="%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n"/>
        </Console>
    </Appenders>
    <Loggers>
        <Root level="all">
            <AppenderRef ref="Console"/>
        </Root>
    </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

Usage in my classes:

```
public class ABCHandler {
    private final Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger();

    public ABC(String serialPortName) {
        logger.info("Opening serial port {}", serialPortName);
    }
}
```

Comment: you should specify class which you want to log, LogFactory.getLogger(ABCHandler.class)

Comment: It'll default to the current class. See ths [Log4j 2 API](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/api.html) for more details.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Loading your file and configurations on my machine works.

This was the class I used:

```
import org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger;

public class Test
{
    private final Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger(Test.class);

    public Test(String serialPortName) {
        System.out.println(logger.isInfoEnabled());
        logger.entry();
        logger.info("info! {}", serialPortName);
        logger.error("error! {}", serialPortName);
        logger.debug("debug! {}", serialPortName);
    }

    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        Test h1 = new Test("1001");
    }
}
```

This is the log4j2.xml:

```
   <ThresholdFilter level="all"/>

 <Appenders>
   <Console name="STDOUT" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
     <PatternLayout pattern="%d %-5p method: [%t] %C{2} (%F:%L) - %m%n"/>
   </Console>
 </Appenders>
 <Loggers>
   <Root level="all">
     <AppenderRef ref="STDOUT"/>
   </Root>
 </Loggers>
```

and finally, this is the output:

`true
2014-05-29 12:19:15,266 TRACE method: [main] Test (Test.java:10) - entry
2014-05-29 12:19:15,268 INFO  method: [main] Test (Test.java:11) - info! 1001
2014-05-29 12:19:15,269 ERROR method: [main] Test (Test.java:12) - error! 1001
2014-05-29 12:19:15,269 DEBUG method: [main] Test (Test.java:13) - debug! 1001`

One common error when using Log4j2 is placing the log4j2.xml in a file that is not in the classpath.

To diagnose if that is the problem, change the line

```
logger.info("Opening serial port {}", serialPortName);
```

to

```
logger.error("Opening serial port {}", serialPortName);
```

If you see any output it is because log4j can't load your file. This is because the default log level when the file is not found is ERROR, not DEBUG.

The location of the log4j2.xml on my project (Maven) is in src/main/resources, which I know it is in my classpath.

Comment: "One common error when using Log4j2 is placing the log4j2.xml in a file that is not in the classpath." That was it...

Comment: Always forgetting about that

Comment: I am facing the same issue where its not printing anything with log.info but log.error gets printed. I added my project to classpath and my log4j2.xml is inside my classpath dir. Am i missing something here?

Comment: Smh... it was sitting in the base project directory. Great write up and example!

Answer (score 1):

My problems were:

1. I was using a `log4j.properties` file. Once renamed to `log4j2.properties` the main and test classpaths picked it up
2. I had to add logging to standard output to `build.gradle`

   ```
   test {
      testLogging.showStandardStreams = true
   }
   ```

note: when I added sourcesets according to [here](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/java_plugin.html#sec:java_project_layout) it still didn't find the `log4j.properties` file only renaming it worked!